# 2D Array isn't storing and displaying data PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm making an Array **Elements** whose each index contains another array **Item** but this item array isn't storing into Elements and hence it is not displaying.
Please help.

```
$item = array();
$elements[] = array();

foreach($html->find('div.jobsearch-SerpJobCard') as $element)
{ 
    $item['title']     = $element->find('div.title', 0)->plaintext;
    $item['salaryText']     = $element->find('span.salaryText', 0);
    $item['summary']     = $element->find('div.summary', 0)->plaintext;
    $elements[]= $item;
}

foreach($elements as $k=>$v)
{
    array_splice($v, 1,1);
    $array[$k] = $v;
    print_r($array[$k]);
}
```

Comment: Try to remove `[]` from `$elements[] = array();`. You're passing an empty array into `0` index and you don't declare `$elements` as an array datatype in such way

Comment: Please can you [edit] your question to include a sample input (something to replace the `$html->find('div.jobsearch-SerpJobCard')` so we can test the code), the output the current code gives, and the output you want instead.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try array push or put an index

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

```
<?php
    //Enter your code here, enjoy!

$jobsearch = array(
    0 => array(
        "title" => "ceo",
        "salary" => 5000,
        "summary" => "high"
        ),
     1 => array(
        "title" => "cto",
        "salary" => 4000,
        "summary" => "low"
        ),
     2 => array(
        "title" => "cio",
        "salary" => 4500,
        "summary" => "medium"
        )
); // example data

$item=array();
$elements[]=array();
foreach($jobsearch as $k => $element)
{
 $item['Ititle'] = $element['title'];
 $item['Isalary']  = $element['salary'];
 $item['Isummary'] = $element['summary'];
 $elements[$k] = $item;


}
var_dump($elements); // got output
```

Comment: Tried. Not Working. Its not displaying anything

Comment: any example data for us to test?

Comment: Actually I'm scraping indeed. You can add any dummy values in the array

Comment: does you php show error while executing the code? maybe the printing part got problem.

Comment: No it doesn't show error. I'm using var_dump also but that's empty too.

Comment: maybe u can use php debugger to go through line by line... so can easily trace out which part is wrong... for me, I use vscode and install php debugger extension...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202382/discussion-between-shehlizah-malik-and-king-theking).

Answer (score 0):

Remove [] from  $elements[] = array();

It is creating an empty array at 0 index for $elements array.